# taking data from 2 different table and inserting it into one table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I'm trying to create a hotel reservation system and right now I'm having trouble in inserting the reservation information into my database.

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $c_username = $_POST['c_username'];
    $r_name = $_POST['r_name'];
    $checkin = $_POST['checkin'];
    $checkout = $_POST['checkout'];
    }
```

I only bring the '*c_username*' , '*r_name*' , '*checkin*' , '*checkout*' from the HTML form tag.... the *c_id* and *r_id* is supposed to be obtain from 2 other database called *cust_info* where *c_id* is located and *accomodation* where *r_id* is located. You can see from below that i have try to obtain it as shown below. However when I try to insert data into the database without commenting the 2nd and 3rd query, none of the data will be insert and it will return an error on the line 
`$query .= "VALUES ( '$c_id', '$c_username', '$r_id', '$r_name', '$checkin', '$checkout' )";`

```
/*$query = "SELECT c.c_id, a.r_id FROM 'cust_info' c JOIN 'accomodation' a WHERE c_username LIKE '{$c_username}' AND r_name LIKE '{$r_name}'";*/

$query = "SELECT c_id FROM cust_info WHERE c_username LIKE '{$c_username}'";

$query = "SELECT r_id FROM accomodation WHERE r_name LIKE '{$r_name}'";

$query = "INSERT INTO reserve( c_id, c_username, r_id, r_name, checkin, checkout)";
$query .= "VALUES ( '$c_id', '$c_username', '$r_id', '$r_name', '$checkin', '$checkout' )";

$create_post_query = mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

This is what my code look like for the moment, when I change the first three query into a comment. The program can insert the data for '*c_username*', '*r_name*', '*checkin*', '*checkout*' into the database.

Thank you

Comment: Aren't your `$query` variables overwriting each other?

Comment: You don't seem to be executing any of the queries, or retrieving the rows from the selects. How do you expect to put a value into $r_id or $c_id?

Comment: @SloanThrasher I realise about that.. do you know anywhere i can learn about mysqli...most site that I visit is not that helping

Comment: @gaganshera Some of my friend did say that it is overwriting each other but even they do not know the solution for it... Is there any site that I can learn about mysqli?...most site that I read is not that helping

Comment: Try googling _mysqli_query prepared example_ for starters. Look at the references on MDN

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you

```
$query = "SELECT c_id FROM cust_info WHERE c_username LIKE '{$c_username}'";
$query_res = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$c_id = mysqli_fetch_array($query_res);


$query2 = "SELECT r_id FROM accomodation WHERE r_name LIKE '{$r_name}'";
$query_res = mysqli_query($con, $query2);
$r_id= mysqli_fetch_array($query_res);


$query = "INSERT INTO reserve( c_id, c_username, r_id, r_name, checkin, checkout)";
$query .= " VALUES ( $c_id, $c_username, $r_id, $r_name, $checkin, $checkout )";

$create_post_query = mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

Comment: It still cannot insert the value of c_id and r_id into table reserve...could it be due to fact that I haven't declare the r_id and c_id as the foreign key in the reserve table